# Tables together

Tags: tables, formatting

I want to put the following table together with a other similar table in two columns

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont{
\rowcolors{1}{}{gray!20}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\rowcolor{LightBlue} \textsf{Plazos} & \textsf{Tasa efectiva anual}\\
\textsf{$30 - 59$ d\'ias} & \textsf{2.00 \%}\\
\textsf{$60 - 90$ d\'ias} & \textsf{2.50 \%}\\
\textsf{$91 - 180$ d\'ias} & \textsf{4.00 \%}\\
\textsf{$181 - 366$ d\'ias} & \textsf{5.00 \%}\\
\textsf{$367 - 546$ d\'ias} & \textsf{6.00 \%}\\
\textsf{$547 - 731$ d\'ias} & \textsf{8.00 \%}\\
\textsf{$732 - 1096$ d\'ias} & \textsf{9.00 \%}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}}}
\caption{Pago de intereses al vencimiento.}
\end{table}
```

I tried with `multicols` but doesn't work.

Comment: You can't use `table` in a `multicols` environment.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to your comment about align tables and captions, I suggest take also a look to the `subfigure`, `subcaption`,  `subfig` or `floatrow` packages for subfloat formats.

On the other hand, although is out of the question, the MWE with `subfigure` include also  `numprint`, `inputenc` and `babel` packages for a better/easier formatting according to Spanish conventions.
[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[spanish,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[normal]{subfigure}
\usepackage{numprint}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\subtable[Cuadro original]{
{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont{
\rowcolors{1}{}{gray!20}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\rowcolor{blue!30} \textsf{Plazos} & \textsf{Tasa efectiva anual}\\
\textsf{$30 - 59$ días} & \textsf{\numprint{2.00} \%}\\
\textsf{$60 - 90$ días} & \textsf{\numprint{2.50} \%}\\
\textsf{$91 - 180$ días} & \textsf{\numprint{4.00} \%}\\
\textsf{$181 - 366$ días} & \textsf{\numprint{5.00} \%}\\
\textsf{$367 - 546$ días} & \textsf{\numprint{6.00} \%}\\
\textsf{$547 - 731$ días} & \textsf{\numprint{8.00} \%}\\
\textsf{$732 - 1096$ días} & \textsf{\numprint{9.00} \%}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}}}
}
\subtable[Cuadro alargado]{
{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont{
\rowcolors{1}{}{gray!20}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\rowcolor{blue!30} \textsf{Plazos} & \textsf{Tasa efectiva anual}\\
\textsf{$30 - 59$ días} & \textsf{\numprint{2.00} \%}\\
\textsf{$60 - 90$ días} & \textsf{\numprint{2.50} \%}\\
\textsf{$91 - 180$ días} & \textsf{\numprint{4.00} \%}\\
\textsf{$181 - 366$ días} & \textsf{\numprint{5.00} \%}\\
\textsf{$91 - 180$ días} & \textsf{\numprint{4.00} \%}\\
\textsf{$181 - 366$ días} & \textsf{\numprint{5.00} \%}\\
\textsf{$367 - 546$ días} & \textsf{\numprint{6.00} \%}\\
\textsf{$547 - 731$ días} & \textsf{\numprint{8.00} \%}\\
\textsf{$732 - 1096$ días} & \textsf{\numprint{9.00} \%}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}}}
}
\caption{Pago de intereses al vencimiento.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach is just to put the two tabulars side-by-side (they're seen by TeX, at some point, as two large characters). Something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
%\rowcolors{1}{}{gray!20}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\textsf{Plazos} & \textsf{Tasa efectiva anual}\\
\textsf{$30 - 59$ d\'ias} & \textsf{2.00 \%}\\
\textsf{$60 - 90$ d\'ias} & \textsf{2.50 \%}\\
\textsf{$91 - 180$ d\'ias} & \textsf{4.00 \%}\\
\textsf{$181 - 366$ d\'ias} & \textsf{5.00 \%}\\
\textsf{$367 - 546$ d\'ias} & \textsf{6.00 \%}\\
\textsf{$547 - 731$ d\'ias} & \textsf{8.00 \%}\\
\textsf{$732 - 1096$ d\'ias} & \textsf{9.00 \%}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\textsf{Plazos} & \textsf{Tasa efectiva anual}\\
\textsf{$30 - 59$ d\'ias} & \textsf{2.00 \%}\\
\textsf{$60 - 90$ d\'ias} & \textsf{2.50 \%}\\
\textsf{$91 - 180$ d\'ias} & \textsf{4.00 \%}\\
\textsf{$181 - 366$ d\'ias} & \textsf{5.00 \%}\\
\textsf{$367 - 546$ d\'ias} & \textsf{6.00 \%}\\
\textsf{$547 - 731$ d\'ias} & \textsf{8.00 \%}\\
\textsf{$732 - 1096$ d\'ias} & \textsf{9.00 \%}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Pago de intereses al vencimiento.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Sorry - as you didn't give a full MWE, I had to remove the `\rowcolor` calls, in preference to spending a lot of time discovering what packages I needed. :-)

Comment: @egreg : Thanks, I didn't spot that particular bit of redundancy

Comment: Don't worry for the colours. I have another problem, the 'other similar table' have a different hight so LaTeX centers vertically them and I'd like to put them at the same hight, the another problem is that I can't put a `caption` in each table without move which should be on the right to above.

Comment: I solved the problem of the hight adding empty rows left the captions, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I believe there are solutions for both of your problems -- two figures in the same float, and aligning the two tables vertically (but I'm not familiar with either, sorry)

Comment: I'm rather dubious about the numbers in the first column, that aren't in sans serif type and the dash is a minus sign, with probably wrong spacing.